# What is the correct approach to maintain relationship between classes (tables) in the following example?

Tags: database-design

In the following  typical example:

**Country** has one-to-many relationship with **City**.
Should **Customer** class have only a reference to **City** or to **Country** as well?

```
public class City
{
    public int CityId { get; set; }
    public int CountryId { get; set; }

    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class Country
{
    public int CountryId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<City> Cities { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public int CityId { get; set; }
    public int CountryId { get; set; }

    public virtual City City { get; set; }
    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Normally even without defining the Customer-Country relationship we can access that via:
*customer.city.country*
and we can maintain the integrity as well.

However, I've mostly seen people add an explicit Customer-Country relationship because *customer.city.country* is weird and they want the simple *customer.country*.
Or in other cases, they create an **Address** class (value object) in between.

What is the correct approach?

Comment: Is it possible to know the customer's country without knowing their city?

Comment: @DavidAldridge what do you think?
This is a generic design question, not my real problem.
if we make it possible then we will lose the integrity. Customer can have USA as Country and London as City (unless we always check the validation in server).

Comment: The ease of use is important, but not as important as data integrity. Also, what's stopping anyone developing the client side classes to expose a Customer.Country property that internally would just give the result of Customer.City.Country?

Comment: @EhsanShirazi I think that either is possible. Sometimes you know high-level information without knowing low-level information. If this was an object oriented design issue I'd say that the relation could be polymorphic, so you can link a customer directly to a city or a country. If you always know the city then just link to that. The "correct approach" depends entirely on the design philosophy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases, you will just want the customer to have a reference to a particular city. It will not be computationally heavy to access a customer's country by using their city, so that should not be a major concern.

The bigger concern would be your data integrity. What happens if a customer's city is Chicago, but their country is China? By having both references, you have to deal with more data validation.

In addition, having the single reference to the city follows the rules of database normalization. If a customer directly references the country, you will violate the 4th normal form (having attributes that can be derived from other attributes).

While we can debate the merits of having a normalized database, in this situation, the relationship between cities and countries is already defined, so there is no need to redefine that relationship by "shortcutting" a foreign key between customers and countries.

Comment: In the 3rd paragraph, did you mean: customer directly referencing the city or country violates 4NF?

Comment: The customer directly referencing the country would violate 4NF, assuming the "true relationship" is between a customer and a city.

This is because the relationship between the country and customer could be determined by using the relationship between customer and city, and the relationship between city and country.

Comment: then I think you should edit that paragraph. Because you have written "If a customer directly references the city, you will violate the 4th normal form".